# Convergence of derivatives of pdfs counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, examples-counterexamples

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of pdfs such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_1(\mu)$, with $f$ being another pdf and $\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure. Are you aware of any examples where the sequence of derivatives of $f_n$ exists and converges pointwise $\mu$ a.e. to some function that is not the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Your question lacks context (why are you wondering this? What effort have you made to find such a pdf yourself?) and will be closed because of this.  That closure is an invitation to you to improve the question so that it can be reopened and answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $f$ the pdf of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$: $f=1_{(0,1)}$. Then you can approximate $f$ with functions of constant slope $1$, e.g.

$f_n(x)=x+1-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n1_{\{x\ge k/n\}}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Then for almost all $x\in(0,1)$, $f_n'(x)=1$, which does not converge to $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: They are not differentiable everywhere but almost everywhere